# Why the npm start is not working like it should?

Tags: npm

I just started a react application and somehow the npm start is not working. I already had a problem on the installation but was able to find a way out however this time I´ve tried a lot of things that i´ve seen here but didn´t work.
I don´t have enougth reputation to put image so here is the error :

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kikaj\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-24T03_13_20_595Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Can you provide the complete output from `npm start`?

Comment: Please write the details about what specific problems you had with examples as well as what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` file. I assume that the script is missing.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: Yes this is how my Json is: "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Comment: @ThiagoBrandão Can you share your file structure and the whole package.json?